# Getting oh-my-zsh 'history' to display command date and time

Tags: oh-my-zsh

The `.zshrc` has the following lines:

```
# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"
```

But uncommenting and running `history` does not work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The .zshrc comment text is misleading.

Use:

`HIST_STAMPS="%d/%m/%y %T"`

To show day, month, year and time respectively.

Comment: and how to remove the command ID to live only the date and time? I've tried with HISTCONTROL=ignoredups but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What would be the best way to raise this doc issue to the maintainers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0) with omz.

**HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"** now works as intended.